# Uploadthing callback error when using 'withAuth' next-auth middleware

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Without middleware no errors in console. But files successfully uploading to uploadthing With or without next-auth middleware. Only callback issue.

Without next-auth middleware
[image: Without next-auth middleware]

With next-auth middleware
[image: With next-auth middleware]

[Github repo](https://github.com/dwalker93/uploadthing-test)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution after reading this

[Uploadthing faqs](https://docs.uploadthing.com/faq#when-i-upload-files-i-get-the-error-failed-to-simulate-callback-for-file-is-your-webhook-configured-correctly)